# Can FactoryGirl set a variable each time an instance is generated?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, ruby-on-rails-4, factory-bot

I am trying assign an array of a new public and private key to a variable for each instance so I can generate a unique and matching bitcoin address and signature.

I am using the [bitcoin-ruby](https://github.com/lian/bitcoin-ruby) gem to generate the keys.

The problem is that I can't figure out where to place `key = Bitcoin::generate_key`

This is my factory without `key = Bitcoin::generate_key`:

```
FactoryGirl.define do
  factory :user do
    sequence(:username)       { |n| "Person #{n}" }
    sequence(:email)          { |n| "person_#{n}@example.com" }
    bitcoin_address           { Bitcoin::pubkey_to_address(key[1]) }
    bitcoin_address_signature { BitcoinCigs.sign_message!(key[0], "test") }
    password                  "examplepass"
    password_confirmation     "examplepass"
  end
end
```

I have tried to put it in the spec helper and everywhere in the file but it is either ignored or generates a syntax error. The closest I have come is this:

```
FactoryGirl.define do
  factory :user do
    sequence(:username)       { |n| "Person #{n}" }
    sequence(:email)          { |n| "person_#{n}@example.com" }
    bitcoin_address           { key = Bitcoin::generate_key
                                Bitcoin::pubkey_to_address(key[1]) }
    bitcoin_address_signature { key = Bitcoin::generate_key
                                BitcoinCigs.sign_message!(key[0], "test") }
    password                  "examplepass"
    password_confirmation     "examplepass"
  end
end
```

Which results in a different key pair for `bitcoin_address` and `bitcoin_address_signature`.

I haven't been able to find a way to make `key` mean the same for both `bitcoin_address` and `bitcoin_address_signature` while still passing the uniqueness validator, am I missing something obvious or am I doing this completely wrong?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use the [`after(:build)`](https://github.com/thoughtbot/factory_girl/blob/master/GETTING_STARTED.md#callbacks) hook:

```
FactoryGirl.define do
  factory :user do
    sequence(:username)       { |n| "Person #{n}" }
    sequence(:email)          { |n| "person_#{n}@example.com" }
    password                  "examplepass"
    password_confirmation     "example pass"

    after(:build) do |user|
      key = Bitcoin::generate_key
      user.bitcoin_address = Bitcoin::pubkey_to_address(key[1])
      user.bitcoin_address_signature = BitcoinCigs.sign_message!(key[0], "test")
    end
  end
end
```